# Build failed with an exception on flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

[image]

I downloaded a flutter theme (a free one from GitHub) when I first time run it, it worked pretty well.

But when I added firebase auth dependency in pubspec.yaml this error in the screenshot started appearing
I tried "flutter clean" and the other posts as well.

Please help me and thanks in advance!

pubspec.yaml

```
name: restaurant_ui_kit
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 5.0+50

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.3.0 ❤.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  introduction_screen: ^1.0.8
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.4+5
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  carousel_slider: ^1.4.1
  provider: ^4.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.3
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/logo.png
    - assets/cc.png
    - assets/on1.png
    - assets/on2.png
    - assets/on3.png
    - assets/food1.jpeg
    - assets/food2.jpeg
    - assets/food3.jpeg
    - assets/food4.jpeg
    - assets/food5.jpeg
    - assets/food6.jpeg
    - assets/food7.jpeg
    - assets/food8.jpeg
    - assets/food9.jpeg
    - assets/food10.jpeg
    - assets/food11.jpeg
    - assets/food12.jpg
    - assets/cm1.jpeg
    - assets/cm2.jpeg
    - assets/cm3.jpeg
    - assets/cm4.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQDTp.png)

Comment: The screenshot is not proper to read the error message. Please edit your question with "flutter run --verbose" result and share your pubspec.yaml file too!

Comment: Please provide us the exception

Comment: @Akif done I re screenshot

Comment: check it now please

Comment: How is your android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file? Can you share it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the android folder of your project and, edit as below,

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
  }
}
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

add this line to file and,

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true // add this line
    }
}

dependencies {
  // add these lines
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' 
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
}
```

and re-run your project.

For more installation information visit [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android)

enjoy :)